# Python: How to get the unordered result from starmap_async

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, unordered, starmap

So the thing is I want to get the return value from the `starmap_async`. However if I use the `.get()` to get the list of the result, it is little slow and same as `starmap`. How do I change the following sample code?

```
full_res = []
def return_result(result):
    full_res.append(result)

with  mp.get_context("spawn").Pool(5,maxtasksperchild=1000) as pool:
            result=pool.starmap_async(fun, [(args)],callback=return_result)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

By the way, I do not need the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of results and you want to get results as they become available, consider using the `concurrent.futures` module instead:

```
import concurrent.futures
import random
import time


def do_work(id):
    sleeptime = random.randint(0, 10)
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
    return id, sleeptime


with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    tasks = [executor.submit(do_work, (x,)) for x in range(10)]
    for task in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tasks):
        print(task.result())
```

Run this code, and you will see that results are displayed as soon as they become available. There is a [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) method available that may be appropriate depending on the nature of your work function; we could rewrite the above like:

```
import concurrent.futures
import random
import time


def do_work(id):
    sleeptime = random.randint(0, 10)
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
    return id, sleeptime


with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    tasks = executor.map(do_work, range(10))
    for result in tasks:
        print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried, but I found the process only use one core. So the speed is not fast as original map in multiprocessing. Thanks again!

Comment: You may want to read the relevant documentation; I assure that you can consume multiple cores using `concurrent.futures` (it is just using the `multiprocessing` module under the hood).

Comment: Well, I checked the document. Thanks!